# what does the tag value used for in this element <a href="url-example" rel="tag">?

Tags: html, web, tags, head

What does the tag value used for in this element

```
<a href="url-example" rel="tag">
```

?
I read this:
"The tag value of the rel attribute gives a tag (identified by the given address) >that applies to the current document."
but I can't understand what the benefit of making a tag for the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the rel="tag" attribute is basically a keyword for SEO

like `<a href="secure/data/photos" rel="nofollow"> photos</a>` prevents google SEO bot from crawling the folder.

Comment: sorry I am new in the feild and I have no knowledge  about seo and crawling.
can you give me a simple answer?

Comment: if a user types into Google "food" the "food" is the keyword and Google goes and finds pages/websites that have the word "food" in them and rank them, so in your scenario "tag". Google will find the word "tag". more about keywords -> https://www.wordstream.com/seo-keyword#:~:text=Your%20SEO%20keywords%20are%20the,connect%20searchers%20to%20your%20site._

Comment: thatnks alot @Ethan.